Querying Entity with @EmbeddedId as pk
I'm migrating from Spring Boot 2 to Spring Boot 3 and I have weird problem with Spring Data Jpa Repository.
I have some entity with composite PK. I'm using @EmbeddedId/@Embedabble do describe this entity.
public class Entity {


@EmbeddedId
private Pk pk;


public static class Pk implements Serializable {
    @Column()
    private String param1;

    @Column()
    private String param2;

I have repository which extends JpaRepository<Entity, Pk> and when i'm calling
List<T> findAllById(Iterable<Pk> ids);

I'm getting very weird invalid query such as :
WHERE e.param1,[*]e.param2 IN (?,?)"; SQL statement:

Composite key columns are listed and separated by coma instead of
WHERE e.param1 = ? AND e.param2 = ? 

I run the same code with spring boot 2 and hibernate 5 and everything works fine.
Any idea what could be the issue ?

Do you have the correct dialect selected? Also using an IN with an array/multiple values is perfectly legal so make sure you are using the right dialect.

Yes, the problem with was with dialect, I had some customization in H2Dialect and query was missing additional ()
It should be:
where (cke1_0.param1, cke1_0.param2) in ((?, ?))
I also didn't know that syntax for WHERE/IN
Thanks !
